# Comparacion de strings en C

Tags: c

estoy tratando de hacer un programa que me valide una contraseña con strcmp para la facultad,pero me da incorrecta,aunque no sea así,creo que puede ser por el uso del memset o que estoy agarrando la contraseña con el getch en vez de un scanf por ejemplo,aunque no lo tengo muy claro,ojala puedan darme una mano. Dejo pedazo del código,desde ya muchas gracias...

```
     while(contrasenia[i] != ENTER && i < CAN_CARACT){
       contrasenia[i] = getch();

if (contrasenia[i] > 32){
     putchar('*');
      i++;}

 else if (contrasenia[i] == DELETE && i > 0){
          putchar(DELETE);
           putchar(' ');
            putchar(DELETE);
             i--;}
                  }


if(strcmp(usuario,"ivan")==0 && strcmp(contrasenia,CLAVE)==0){

   printf("\n\n Bienvenido %s",usuario);
     verifi = 1;}
```

Answer (score 2):

Tu código, tal y como está es completamente ilegible, para las pocas líneas que tiene es complicado saber dónde empieza y dónde acaba el `while`, por ejemplo. Tabulando correctamente el código quedaría así (la posición de las llaves es cuestión de gustos):

```
while(contrasenia[i] != ENTER && i < CAN_CARACT)
{
    contrasenia[i] = getch();

    if (contrasenia[i] > 32)
    {
        putchar('*');
        i++;
    }
    else if (contrasenia[i] == DELETE && i > 0)
    {
        putchar(DELETE);
        putchar(' ');
        putchar(DELETE);
        i--;
    }
}
```

Fíjate que ahora cada ámbito está claramente identificado y el código es más fácil de seguir.

Pues bien, ignoro a qué equivale `ENTER`, pero si suponemos que vale `\n` y el usuario introduce como contraseña `1234`, lo que obtendrá en `contrasenia` será `1234\n[basura]`, cuando lo esperable habría sido `1234\0` ya que como bien sabes, en C las cadenas finalizan con `\0`. Si no añades ese caracter final, tu contraseña no podrá compararse con `strcmp`. Así de simple.

Así pues el código podría quedar así:

```
while(contrasenia[i] != ENTER && i < CAN_CARACT)
{
  // ...
}
contrasenia[i] = '\0'; // Reemplazamos \n por \0
```

Y con este cambio ya debería funcionar.

Comment: Hola,disculpa la desproligidad,no suelo usar esta pagina,y no la entiendo muy bien,el ENTER valdría 13, para que cuando el usuario lo oprima se salga del while.Con respecto a añadir el '\0'; no lo entendí muy bien la verdad,pero agradezco tu tiempo,muchas gracias.

Comment: Ya lo entendí,te agradezco eferion.